# Rails Display Link in Database Using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I have a "notifications" class, one field of which is "link". The links contained within this class are formatted like: **exchange_path(6)**, where that is the path to the show action in the exchange controller.

I'm now trying to output this link as such:

```
<%= link_to "View Exchange", notification.link %>
```

This line is in a loop which begins as such:

```
<% @notifications.each do |notification| %>
```

When I click this link, it takes me to **localhost:3000/users/exchange_path(6)** instead of **localhost:3000/exchanges/6** like I would expect. (The loop generating the faulty link is on localhost:3000/users/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<%= link_to("View Exchange", "/#{notification.link.gsub('(', '/').gsub(')', '').gsub('_path', 's')}") %>
```

or set up a method in your model that formats it for you:

```
def format_link
  link.gsub('(', '/').gsub(')', '').gsub('_path', 's')
end
```

and just call that in your link_to:

```
link_to("View Exchanges", notification.format_link)
```

This will only work if all the links are formatted exactly as the example in the question

Comment: Thanks, but this takes me directly to localhost:3000/exchange_path(8) rather than calling the controller action

Comment: Didn't see the formatting you included at first, that now works correctly!

Answer (score 1):

this could be scary...

```
<%= link_to "View Exchange", eval(notification.link) %>
```

should evaluate and use the path helpers.  but you need to be 100% sure that nothing bad gets put in the link field..

Comment: Thank you, this would work as well but I went with the above answer due to the security concerns you raised.